# Possible to call C++ code from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, unmanaged, managed

Is it possible to call C++ code, possibly compiled as a code library file (.dll), from within a .NET language such as C#?

Specifically, C++ code such as the RakNet networking library.

Comment: Unmanged c++ to mangaged c#: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/tanmayit08/unmanaged-cpp-dll-call-from-managed-C-Sharp-application/

Answer (score 102, accepted):

One easy way to call into C++ is to create a wrapper assembly in C++/CLI.  In C++/CLI you can call into unmanaged code as if you were writing native code, but you can call into C++/CLI code from C# as if it were written in C#.  The language was basically designed with interop into existing libraries as its "killer app".

For example - compile this with the /clr switch

```
#include "NativeType.h"

public ref class ManagedType
{
     NativeType*   NativePtr; 

public:
     ManagedType() : NativePtr(new NativeType()) {}
     ~ManagedType() { delete NativePtr; }

     void ManagedMethod()
      { NativePtr->NativeMethod(); } 
};
```

Then in C#, add a reference to your ManagedType assembly, and use it like so:

```
ManagedType mt = new ManagedType();
mt.ManagedMethod();
```

Check out [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140806022309/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/borisj/archive/2006/09/28/769708.aspx) for a more explained example.

Comment: link is broken for blog post :(

Answer (score 11):

P/Invoke is a nice technology, and it works fairly well, except for issues in loading the target DLL file. We've found that the best way to do things is to create a static library of native functions and link that into a Managed C++ (or C++/CLI) project that depends upon it.

Comment: I've had issues with callbacks and p/invoke. Switching over to C++ / CLI has addressed these issues.

Comment: How debugging works in this case?

Answer (score 9):

I'm not familiar with the library you mentioned, but in general there are a couple ways to do so:

- [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) to exported library functions
- Adding a reference to the COM type library (in case you're dealing with COM objects).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is called [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke).

Here's a great resource site for using it with the Win32 API:

http://www.pinvoke.net/

Answer (score 2):

Sure is. [This article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/article.php/c4217) is a good example of something you can do to get started on this.

We do this from C# on our Windows Mobile devices using [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The technology used to do this is called [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services); you can search for articles on the subject. Note that it is for calling C from C#, not C++ so much. So you'll need to wrap your C++ code in a C wrapper that your DLL exports.

Answer (score -3):

Have you considered Apache Thrift?

http://thrift.apache.org/

It seems like a very very neat solution.

Comment: [Apache Thrift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Thrift) - *"Thrift is an interface definition language and binary communication protocol used for defining and creating services for numerous programming languages."*

Comment: How does that answer the question? It is essentially a link-only answer. Can you elaborate in your answer (in your own words)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4280372/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: OK, the OP has probably left the building (*"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*)