# Dependency parsing

Tags: c#, nlp, dependencies, tree-grammar

I particularly like the transduce feature offered by agfl in their EP4IR 
http://www.agfl.cs.ru.nl/EP4IR/english.html

The download page is here:
http://www.agfl.cs.ru.nl/download.html

Is there any way i can make use of this in a c# program? Do I need to convert classes to c#?

Thanks
:)

Comment: Do you want the exact dependency representation produced by EP4IR, or would other representations also possibly work?

Comment: I found that EP4IR gives the most accurate dependency relations so this would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on using EP4IR, I think the question boils down to: how can you call non-.NET C++ code in C#. From a prior [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c), it looks like there are a few ways to do this, including using [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx) or writing a C++.NET wrapper around the non-.NET code you want to call. C++.NET was specifically designed to make it easy to call legacy non-.NET code.

If you are willing to try out other dependency representations, you might want to take a look at [Antelope](http://www.proxem.com/Antelope/tabid/55/Default.aspx). It's a rather complete .NET based natural language processing toolkit. It'll allow you to use both the [Link parser](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/) ([demo](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html)) and the [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) ([demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/)). Both of these will give you a reasonably good typed dependency representation for a sentence.