# Calling a C++ code from C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, interop, visual-c++-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to call C++ code from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c)

I have an issue. I have a project that requires me to call a code that was written in Visual C++ 6.0 by someone else from my VS2008 C# code. I was wondering if anyone know how to do this. Thanks

Comment: I want to see some answers here too...

Comment: Possible duplication of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c

Comment: you can call C libraries (see P-Invoke) and COM.

Answer (score 0):

If the assembly is COM visible you can add it as a reference to your C# project.

If not, you can use [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) to do so. Also, [PInvoke.net](http://Pinvoke.net) is an invaluable resource for this sort of thing.