# C# Wrapper How to

Tags: c#, c++

I've got a DLL that is written in C++ and I want to create a C# wrapper for
 it. I know this can be done, but I'm not sure how
 to go about this. I've got VS 2010 and I've been looking on the net, but
 not alot of clear definitions out there. For now, until I get he hang of it,
 my c++ DLL is pretty basic, as it only has functions that take in and return
 integers.

Can anyone provide an example, or point to a good place on the web?

Comment: The answers to this question should point you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a (static) method with the `extern` keyword to stand in for the native function and use the [`DllImport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) custom attribute on it.

There is a [tutorial on consuming unmanaged DLL functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc.aspx) on MSDN.