# Best way to make a C++ software package and C# package access same enumeration/constant ints

Tags: c#, c++, header-files

I am developing a software package that transmits messages. Currently I have a header file that contains definition of message IDs. My coworker is creating a software tool in C# and needs access to these IDs. What is the best way for our software to access these IDs?

More details:
He and I don't have control over what language we use. He wants to make 2 copies of the same list. I am always hesitant to make copies of the same code. (There will be a lot of message IDs). Is there an easy way for both these tools to access the same ID?

Comment: simply use cli, have a look [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c

Comment: @mo.: By the way, only the shorthand `[label](URL)` syntax works in comments.  The `[label][ref], [ref]: URL` stuff can only be used in other types of posts (questions, answers, etc.).  Check the "help" button at the right of your comment for details.

Comment: It's cool mo, I can still see the link. :)

Comment: it was an answer :) it was automatically converted to a comment.here is link in a nicier [-->way<--](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++/CLI is your friend. I had the exact same scenario in one of my projects and I found C++/CLI very usefull in this respect. My design was based on 3 layers:

```
C#
_______
C++/CLI
_______
C++
```

This way, I could easily **reuse** my C++ definitions without **any duplications**

Answer (score 2):

You could specify the IDs in some declarative, trivial to parse grammar and have your (automatic) build process generate C# and C++ source files out of it. That way you have one single source.