# C/C++ to C# converter or emulator

Tags: c#, c++, c, emulation, converters

Assume that I have some C code for a portable, non-visual library. The code relies mostly on CRT (there is no QT/DirectX/WinAPI etc. dependencies).

Is there a way I could use this code in a C# application? I know about Managed C++ and that's **not** an acceptable way for me.

I thought of a C/C++ to C# converter that I could use for automatic translation (I don't need a *readable* output, a working one is enough) or an emulator that I could use to execute compiled C/C++ code.

Do you know of anything that might help me to use existing C/C++ code from C# code?

EDIT:

P/Invoke is not an acceptable way too. As well as calling external EXE or using COM/ActiveX. I need something that will allow me to incorporate C and C# code into one managed DLL or EXE.

Existing C code is a library (.lib), not an EXE.

Comment: Is this C code a proper executable or just a library? Anyway you could use P/Invoke for C library or execute in case of an exe and catch the output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c

Comment: If you don't need to maintain the code, why won't you create a DLL and reference it...
such as COM+ object

Comment: Translation is unlikely to be practical, as C# code does not have pointers and translating pointer-based code to non-pointer-based code is virtually impossible to automate.

Comment: Why is it so critical to have one single file as the output?
It's not very usual for windows apps to have a single executable and no accompanying files.

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov because I know plenty of methods to do this without this restriction ;-)

Comment: Based on "Existing code is a `.lib`", do you have source code or not?

Comment: @BenVoigt I do have all code required to build a .lib

Comment: @Thom: Pointers may not be recommended style in C#, but they certainly do exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not temporarily compile the C++ as managed C++, to get a .net assembly, then use Reflector to decompile it into pure C#?

Comment: This is as close to automated as you can get, however the results are not likely to be pretty.

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov: Pure managed, yes.  Safe and verifiable, no.  As a result, not all pure C++/CLI assemblies can be perfectly decompiled to C#.

Comment: +1 this is ugly but it's the only answer that seems to solve OP's problem.

Comment: It looks like this is the only *automated* way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easiest to use the methods directly from the DLL without converting the code to C#. That works pretty well, one disadvantage being that you have to ship multiple binaries for different platforms.
Importing functions from Dll is as easy as

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress (IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);
```

I don't think incorporating both C and C# code in one DLL is feasible without converting the former.