# How to use C++ dll exported class in c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to call C++ code from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c)

I have C++ class, that have some static method. It is in the dll, that exports class. I need to use static method from C# project. Can I do it without COM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 ways:

wrapping the native C++ dll with a [C++\CLI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes) one  or using [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx)

Comment: In PInvoke all examples are about simple functions, is there a way to use it with class methods?

Comment: @hellohi you will have to declare a handle look at the gdi32.dll example

Answer (score 2):

COM would be a good way to do it (other than the fact that COM doesn't support static methods...)

Another way is to turn the class into a C++/CLI managed class like this:

```
public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    static void StaticMethod()
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

A C++/CLI managed class in a DLL will be visible to C# just as if it were a C# class.

If you don't want to turn the C++ project into a C++/CLI project, you can create a C++/CLI project containing a managed class which just wraps the unmanaged class in the unmanaged C++ project.