# how to use C++ code of an application in C#

Tags: c#

I have an application of live broadcaster in C/C++ with lots of API and Graphics. now i have to make design in C#
. please help me how to integrate both. Thanks in advance

Comment: C# can call C functions, and C++ code can be made to look like C for external use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to call C++ code from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/borisj/archive/2006/09/28/769708.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can create a dll project in C++ and import the C++ dll into C# project. For more details, you can refer to:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx
2. If you want to use C++ in c# code directly, you can create a CLR(C++/CLI) project, then you can write c++ and c# code in the same project.  For more details, please refer to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163852.aspx
and 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/cppcliintro01.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Create a C interfaces and the call methods using PInvoke
2. Create a C++/CLI wrapper

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c) answer for more information

Comment: There are more options actually, but those two are easier.