# Using the same cryptography approach in both C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, cryptography, wincrypt

**CONTEXT:** I'm developing an application that requires a licensing process to add some security to it. The application is major C#, but it has a small portion (an independent module, in fact) of it written in C++.

The latter already has a licensing process implemented, which in summary consists of: when the app initializes, it looks for a license file containing encrypted info, generated by the developers based on some customer info (a `string`). If the file is valid, the app continues your execution, otherwise, it shuts down. The important part of it is that it uses the `wincrypt.h` library to add cryptography to strings.

**DESIRE:** Both parts (or modules) must have a license-based security and should share the same license file.

**PROBLEM:** I'm trying to adapt the security process described before to C# in order to use it on the other part of the app. I haven't found a way of using `wincrypt.h` functions to do so (maybe because my knownledge of C# is not that great, or maybe because I simply can't do that). I ended up using RSA, but I ended up with two different cryptograph methods.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way of using `wincrypt.h` in C#? If not, is there any other way of developing a (en|de)cription of a `string` process that can be used in both C++ and C#?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check this previous question it should have everything you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c

Comment: @MarcoFatica Thanks for the link, even thought doesn't seem that simple (deep down, I knew it wouldn't be), I'll study it and give it a shot.