# How to call VC++ code from C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, sdk

i am working with windows C# wpf desktop app ,i have vc++ sdk project and i want to call sdk features from C# app but i don't know how to call vc++ functions from c# please help me.
thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to call C++ code from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [C++/CLI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx) wrapper. Basically, you can call into this wrapper from c# as you would call other managed code. From within the wrapper, you can call native code as from other native code.

Comment: Yes,i want exactly same thing.but i having SDK which runs only on release  mode and that SDK  having lots of file and i don't not c++ more.so i am little bit confuse how to do.