# How to trigger C++ code with event grid in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to upload a blob in the Azure storage and it uploads successfully. Now the next step is to process the blob with C++ code.
Since Azure function does not support C++ how can I process the blob?

Comment: you'd have to first build your binaries and ensure that you are able to run them from .net/python/javascript code. once you are able to do that, now you can upload those binaries together wherever you've published your azure function.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Function support running `.exe` executable file. So I suggest generating your cpp program exe file, then upload it to Azure Function and run the below sample code.

[image]

```
using System;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTriggerCSharp1\testfunc.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.Start();
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();

    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By now on Azure Functions as the comment said, there are .NET, Python, Node.js, Java supported, no C++.

However, if you are working on Linux, you can consider for calling C++ in Python or Node.js, such as following the documents for Python with [`Extending Python with C or C++`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/extending.html) or for Node.js with [`C++ Addons`](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html). I think there are simpler for you to use event grid with Azure Function.

And there is an existing SO thread about [Calling C/C++ from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python) that you can refer to.

Or else for working on Windows, the other solution is to compile your C++ code to a dynamic library in Visual Studio, and then you can invoke the dll lib in C++ from C# code. Please refer to the MSDN document [`Calling Native Functions from Managed Code`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/calling-native-functions-from-managed-code?view=vs-2019) to know it, or refer to the SO thread [Possible to call C++ code from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c).

Hope it helps.