# Combine C++ application inside C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have an OpenGL application written in C++, but I need the user interface for sharing data into the renderer. I am curious: can I, e.g create a dynamically linked library and connect it into some of the C#'s GUI frameworks (WinForms, WPF) and use my renderer in some context?

Comment: Hi, have you checked this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c

Comment: Wpf and (I assume) winforms have allowed c++ as the development language for awhile now. Technically c++/cli, but…..

Comment: @Taekahn I think the problem is not the interop in this case (though I agree C++/cli is best for that), it is the C++ library generating graphical output. I see possibilities if the C++ only does calculations and the actual drawing is done from C#... or if there is a way to get a HWND (or HBITMAP) from C# to the opengl stuff in the dll (though I wouldn't know how).